# Unable to seed database in rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

11.2.2

First I migrated db(bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset), then I try to seed it(bundle exec rake db:seed) and I get this message:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/aki/sample_app/db/seeds.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/home/aki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

This is mine `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
User.create!(name:  "Example User",
             email: "example@railstutorial.org",
             password:              "foobar",
             password_confirmation: "foobar",
             admin: true,
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name:  name,
               email: email,
               password:              password,
               password_confirmation: password,
               activated: true,
               activated_at: Time.zone.now)

users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

Comment: You're missing an `end` on your 99.times block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
99.times do |n|
 name  = Faker::Name.name
 email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
 password = "password"
 User.create!(name:  name,
           email: email,
           password:              password,
           password_confirmation: password,
           activated: true,
           activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end #This is the missing end and your sytax error
```

Comment: When I added 'end' there (before I posted question), my console kept running for too long so I canceled it few times.. Now it is fine. Thanks!