# Heroku run rake db:seed gives expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm doing chapter 11 of [hartle](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts)'s tutorial.
At the end of this chapter I ran

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

And I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /app/db/seeds.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

This is my seeds.rb file:

```
User.create!(name:  "Example User",
             email: "example@railstutorial.org",
             password:              "foobar",
             password_confirmation: "foobar",
             admin:     true,
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name:  name,
              email: email,
              password:              password,
              password_confirmation: password,
              activated: true,
              activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

I didn't have any problem with seed.db till now!

Comment: Are you sure posted code and code deployed to heroku are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "expected keyword_end" error means you have a syntax error in the specified file. You'll see this a lot, especially in your test suite; get cozy with it.

Go through the file with a fine-tooth comb and mentally match up each `{` with its `}` and each `do` with its `end`. Usually you discover that one of these is mismatched.

If you can't find the mismatch, comment out your entire seed file and run `rake db:seed` again. The error should not appear. Then progressively uncomment each section of the file until you figure out where the error comes from.

This is tedious but it works.

Comment: It's strange because the rake test didn't return any error. It's the same code in tutorial...Maybe I can't notice something here...

Comment: In this case, you only got the error on `rake db:seed` because that's the only command that loads the `seeds.rb` file; other commands don't need it. Anyway follow the uncommenting process described above and you should find the error pretty quickly (and hopefully learn how to spot it quicker in the future).

Comment: I can't see any mismatch in my file. I even check with the same file in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374671/unable-to-seed-database-in-rails-tutorial

Comment: Did you follow the uncommenting process? When you comment out everything in the file, then run `rake db:seed`, you shouldn't see the error. Then gradually uncomment each section until you've identified what specific lines of code the error is on.

Comment: The problem is I'm dealing with another error so when I run rake on local it shows me the other one!!!

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to that one.( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973162/missing-required-arguments-aws-access-key-id-aws-secret-access-key-on-rake-tes )

Comment: Yeah errors can be a real pain to deal with especially when they stack up. But it sounds like this specific issue got resolved? If so please consider marking the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Actually at least in my case it didn't. But the answer maybe useful for some other guys. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a Similar Problem

class Tag < ApplicationRecord::Base
    has_many :destinations
end
end

I had Double "end end " in my model... I deleted one "end" and the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Just run your file in a terminal and you should get sufficient information to hunt down the good old `unexpected end-of-input`-syntax error. If you specify the `-w`-option, you will be presented with additional warnings as well, that often contain the relevant hints you need.

In your case: Run this in your terminal (from your project's root dir):

```
ruby -w db/seeds.rb
```

Now you should get an output detailing your syntax error in `seeds.rb` with a line number (along with other warnings and errors, if there are any), e.g. something like:

```
db/seeds.rb:19: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'unless' at 12
db/seeds.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
...
...
```